# C++, Class issues using .h and .cpp files, function 'getEstimate' will not run

Tags: c++, class

For some reason, even though I think the class is created right for the use of header files, nothing will transfer over. I'm trying to send some data into a class to do some simple math with, and then send the results back. However, I've given you the basis behind the code, I just need the transfer of data between the files to work.

Here is the code:

-----------------------------------------main.cpp----------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Estimate.h" //incloude class file

using namespace std;

int main() {//open main

    int labour = 3, travel = 4, copper = 2, plastic = 1, chrome = 2;//initialise integers

    //constructer for class Job - passing through all the variables above.
    Estimate Job(labour, travel, copper, plastic, chrome);

    //CALL FUNCTION to print invoice
    Job.getEstimate();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}//close main
```

--------------------------------------------Estimate.h------------

```
class Estimate          {//open classs

public:

    int labour, travel, copper, plastic, chrome, subTotal;
    float total, vat;

    Estimate(int, int, int, int, int);
    ~Estimate();

    void getEstimate()  {}

};//close estimate
```

--------------------------Estimate.cpp-------------------------------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Estimate.h"

int labour, travel, copper, plastic, chrome, subTotal;
float total, vat;

//constructor and destructor
Estimate::Estimate(int labour,int travel, int copper, int plastic, int chrome)  {
    this -> labour  = labour;
    this -> travel  = travel;
    this -> copper  = copper;
    this -> plastic = plastic;
    this -> chrome  = chrome;
}//constructor

Estimate::~Estimate()   {}//destructor

void getEstimate()  {
    std::cout << "################### Estimate ###################";
    system("pause");
}//function
```

---

Comment: Does it compile even? You seem to be missing '<' in `include iostream>`
`include string>` for starters.

Comment: And replace `{}` with `;` at the end of the `getEstimate` declaration in the header. That's an empty definition; you want the definition in the cpp. Also, you need `Estimate::getEstimate` in the cpp.

Comment: Please make sure you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yeah while I was writing the code if I put #include it would be big and bold and if I put a < then it remover what ever followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with code that compiles. as is mentioned by [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin) you need to do `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>`

Now, in your header you define `Estimate::getEstimate` as an empty function `{}`.
And in your implementation you define a scoped function `getEstimate`.

Change the line in your header to:

```
void getEstimate();
```

And the line in your implementation to:

```
void Estimate::getEstimate(){
```

Comment: Marcin, sje397 - Thank you too

will read that now Rook